# How to change Indent "arrow" color in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using a dark-style theme so the arrows that represent the "Tab Spaces" are not shown unless I cursor-select a part of code(as shown below in the image).

[image]

I just want to change the color of the arrows to grey(or something that will be visible)

I've searched in workbench color -> settings.json but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following item in your `settings.json`. Replace `YOUR COLOR THEME` at line 2 with the full name of your color theme (eg. `"[Monokai Pro]": {`)

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "[YOUR COLOR THEME]": {
      "editorWhitespace.foreground": "#ff0000",
  }
}
```

Results:

[image: results]

Comment: Is there a way to change the color when the tab is not selected?